# Target = iframe links don't work in Fire Fox

Tags: firefox, iframe, hyperlink, target

I'm building a page that has links on the left of the screen that target an iframe. They work just fine in the new IE, but not at all in FireFox. I've played around with their Z-index, but can't seem to get them to be recognized in FireFox. They don't just not work, but the mouse cursor doesn't even show that they are links on hover. The address for the page I'm working on is at the address below.

http://www.snoscoot.com/fcaccessories/hondapowerequipment/test.html

An example of the code for one of the buttons is as follows:

`<A HREF="http://www.snoscoot.com//fcaccessories/hondapowerequipment/subcompacttractorpartsandinformation.html" TARGET="productdisplay"><IMG SRC="http://www.snoscoot.com/fcaccessories/hondapowerequipment/hondatractorparts150px.jpg" border="0">
<font size="3" color="black" face="Arial">Subcompact tractor parts</font></a>`

The code I have for the targeted iFrame is as follows:

`<IFRAME
    SRC="http://www.snoscoot.com/fcaccessories/hondapowerequipment/compacttractorpartsandinformation.html"
    NAME="productdisplay"
    WIDTH=700 HEIGHT=1622
    frameBorder="0"
scrolling="no">
</IFRAME>`

Would anyone have some advice as to how to get the links to function in FireFox? I can't seem to figure out why they work in IE, but not in FF.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe inside the `<div id="dropdown">` is 1500px tall by 950px wide and hence covers up most of the rest of the page.  In particular it's sitting above those links, so they can't be clicked.

Are you sure you want it to be 1500px tall?